# read apm env variable from env file golang

Tags: go, environment-variables, apm

I'm using elastic apm for my go app during
 development i export env variable through the terminal and it's working.
but now i want to deploy the app so i need to read variables from the  .env file

explanation

i use `go.elastic.co/apm/module/apmhttp` at my app
and when `go.elastic.co/apm` read env variables, 
it can't see `ELASTIC_APM_SERVICE_NAME`, `ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URL` or `ELASTIC_APM_SECRET_TOKEN`
that existed at my .env on my app files.

Comment: Recheck gotenv.Load() in init or before initing the struct

Comment: @MuhamedKeta `gotenv.Load()` working well, but the problem is that `go.elastic.co/apm` can't see env variables

Comment: This is probably an issue with [initialization order](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization). [go.elastic.co/apm reads the environment variables in its init method](https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-go/blob/d4ce90a/tracer.go#L62). We can't tell for sure or offer solutions without seeing some code. If you [create your own Tracer](https://godoc.org/go.elastic.co/apm#NewTracer) after loading your file it'll probably work.

Comment: @Peter Thank you peter i created new tracer and it works now

Comment: Hi @M7Shapan would you mind posting the solution? Thanks!

Comment: @HongboMiao i hope my solution reach you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the answer to my question I hope it helps you @HongboMiao

```
// close default Tracer
apm.DefaultTracer.Close()

tracer, err := apm.NewTracer(os.Getenv("ELASTIC_APM_SERVICE_NAME"), os.Getenv("VERSION"))
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}

transport, err := transport.NewHTTPTransport()
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}

transport.SetSecretToken(os.Getenv("ELASTIC_APM_SECRET_TOKEN"))
u, err := url.Parse(os.Getenv("ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URL"))
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}

transport.SetServerURL(u)
tracer.Transport = transport

// this step will be difference depend on your webserver package
r.Use(apmchi.Middleware(apmchi.WithTracer(tracer)))
```